# OnStateChanged Method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, state

In Flutter, is there a method like ***onStateChanged*** which is called when the state of the page changes?

```
setState(() {
  widget._loadCompleted = true;
  widget._loading = false;
});
```

I'm trying to set the two bool values in `setState()` method. I'm setting states for several other reasons. So I want to know if the last state change was for this particular reason.

Comment: How would `onStateChanged` help? There is no such thing anyway.

Comment: @Vishnu I edited my answer with code, did that help you?

Answer (score 3):

As Günter mentioned, there is no such thing like `onStateChanged()`. You have to deal it in `build()` method.

If I got you right, you can use like this:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool myFlag = false; // initially set to false

  void _doYourWork() {
    setState(() => myFlag = true); // set to true here
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (myFlag) {
      // setState() just got called
    } else {
       // we are building fresh for the first time. 
    }
    myFlag = false;
    return yourWidget();
  }
}
```

After this `build()` will receive `myFlag` value to `true` and it can then set to `false` again. So, you can do this trick.